# Ferramenta para modelagem de dados

Tags: modelagem

Existe alguma ferramenta para modelagem de dados **free** em que eu possa fazer um **reverse engineering** de um **banco Sql Server ( express 2012)** sem ser a [DBDesegner Fork](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/) ?

Comment: Sim, a própria IDE do SQL Server (o SQL Server Management Studio): https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189078.aspx.